# Every time I use OnCollisionEnter2D it does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make that the ball every time it hits the paddles increase its velocity but it does not works

ball.cs

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float velocityMultiplier = 1.1f;

    private void OnCollisioEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Paddle"))
        {
            ballRb.velocity *= velocityMultiplier;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Paddle A inspector

[PaddleA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx8ce.png)

and Paddle B is the same

Answer (score 0):

Your colldier seems to be marked as *Kinematic*. It does not respond to colliders, and can only be moved with Scripts.

From docs:

> **Kinematic Rigidbody Collider**
>
> > This is a GameObject with a Collider and a kinematic Rigidbody attached (ie, the IsKinematic property of the Rigidbody is enabled). You can move a kinematic rigidbody object from a script by modifying its Transform Component
> > but it will not respond to collisions and forces like a non-kinematic rigidbody. Kinematic rigidbodies should be used for colliders that can be moved or disabled/enabled occasionally but that should otherwise behave like static colliders. An example of this is a sliding door that should normally act as an immovable physical obstacle but can be opened when necessary. Unlike a static collider, a moving kinematic rigidbody will apply friction to other objects and will “wake up” other rigidbodies when they make contact.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).